# How to insert jlist as a single block in MySQL data

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jtable, jlist

I have created a java software application in which there is a form and that contains few JTextField and one JList. The items in the JList is also inserted by the user with the help of a JTextField present in the same page. I want to save the JTextField and the JList in MySQL database on clicking the submit button. I have successfully inserted the JTextField data in MySQL database table but the problem is that I don't know how to save JList in single block . Just to practice, I have tried to save JList and its taking new row for each item in the database.

Is there any way I can add the entire JList in single block.

OR

If not how can I link the JList with the remaining data in MySQL.

I know we can ask only one question at a time but the other problem is how to retrieve JList from the database to JTable in the form of JList within the JTable with all other details.

```
    DefaultListModel dlm= new DefaultListModel();
    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

        String userInput= jTextField1.getText();
        dlm.addElement(userInput);
        jList1.setModel(dlm);
        jTextField1.setText(null);  

    }                                        

String item="";
    private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

       for(int i = 0; i < jList1.getModel().getSize(); i++)
       {         item = (String)jList1.getModel().getElementAt(i);
        try{

                    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                    Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/a","root","");
                    PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement("insert into listt (listitem) values (?)");
                    stmt.setString(1,item);
                    stmt.execute();
                    conn.close();
        }
catch(Exception e){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }       
       } 
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Done");
    }
```

The above code has two buttons btn1 is adding JTextField data to JList and btn2 is adding the JList item to database. Its saving each item in new row in the database but I want to save it in a single row in a single block with other data.

Code Using for displaying the data from MySQL to JList and jTable:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

        try{

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/a","root","");
            String query="SELECT listitem FROM listt;";
            PreparedStatement prepstmt=conn.prepareStatement(query);            
            ResultSet rs=prepstmt.executeQuery(); 

            while(rs.next()){

                String item= rs.getString(1);
                dlm.addElement(item);
                jList1.setModel(dlm);

            }

        }catch(Exception e){

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }

    }
```

Image of current JTable result.
![https://imgur.com/dPlnLVu]

Code for Jtable is here:

```
 private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {  



    Update_table();

}                                        

private void Update_table(){

    try{

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ft","root","");
        String query="SELECT * FROM ftt;";
        PreparedStatement prepstmt=conn.prepareStatement(query);  
        ResultSet rs=prepstmt.executeQuery(); 
        jTable1.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));

    }catch(Exception e){

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
}
```

The items in the listitem column are supposed to be in JList for each row and also null show not be displayed iit is auto generated in the Mysql database when saving the jlist value to database.

Rest of the things are solved but I still need to generate JList within the jTable.

Comment: You can add all list element in String array like first value::secondvalue::thirdvalue save that string array in database

Comment: @KamalKumar null is not showing now in Jlist thanks.

Comment: you can accept my answer

Comment: @KamalKumar you suggested me a link regarding Jlist in Jtable but its doesn't helped me.  Please if you can help.

Comment: describe where you stuck? explain your problem

Comment: @Kamalkumar I have linked the image of my JTable which is fetching data from MySQL database. The problem is that in my database I have a JtextField and a jList entry, the textfield entry is showing fine but the jlist item is also generated in a single row. I ant it to appear as a Jlist it the row clicking on which it will display all the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 String allitem="";
    for(int i = 0;i<jList1.getModel().getSize();i++)
    {
        allitem = (String)jList1.getModel().getElementAt(i)+"::"+allitem;
    }

try
{
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/a", "root", "");
    PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement("insert into listt (listitem) values (?)");
    stmt.setString(1, allitem);
    stmt.execute();
    conn.close();
}catch(
Exception e)
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

try this one

Answer (score 0):

```
   while(rs.next()){

        String item= rs.getString(1);
        String[] arrOfStr = item.split("::"); 
        for (String a : arrOfStr) {
            dlm.addElement(a);
            jList1.setModel(dlm);
        }

    }
```

Replace your while block with above

Comment: All the code provided by @KamalKumar are correct and working fine for me.